# Get a lazy PersistentCollection without a database call

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, lazy-loading

Is there a way to get a Collection property of an entity when you already know the id of the parent entity and you also know that the entity actually exists on the database, **without triggering a database query**?

The simplest way to get such a collection is of course to use a `EntityManager.find()`, but it makes an an unnecessary database query:

```
    MyEntity entity = em.find(MyEntity.class, id); // prints "select ... from MyEntity"
    Collection c = entity.getSomeChildren();
```

I had assumed that `EntityManager.getReference()` will do the trick but unfortunately even with `getReference()` the database is queried when `entity.getSomeChildren()` is called, despite it being a `FetchType.LAZY` property:

```
    MyEntity entity = em.getReference(MyEntity.class, id);
    Collection c = entity.getSomeChildren();       // prints "select ... from MyEntity"
```

Fortunately it does not issue a `"select ... from MyEntity_SomeChildren"` query unless I actually call some method on `c`, and I understand that this last effect is exactly because of the `FetchType.LAZY` annotation. But I think even the first query is redundant.

Here is the code for `MyEntity`

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    private String id;
    private Collection<SomeChildren> someChildren;

    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Collection<SomeChildren> getSomeChildren() {
        return someChildren;
    }

    public void setSomeChildren(Collection<SomeChildren> someCollection) {
        this.someChildren = someCollection;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: Why do I need this?**
The full scenario is something like this: I have a `MyEntity` instance which I got from a query with `new` operator:

```
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    List<MyEntity> list = em.createQuery("select new MyEntity(...) from MyEntity e where ...").getResultList();
    MyEntity original = list.get(0);
    return  original;
```

This works fine, but sometimes (and only *sometimes*) I need `entity.getSomeChildren()`. Consequently I don't want to pass it to the constructor, so I thought of this trick:

```
    MyEntity original = list.get(0);
    MyEntity entity = em.getReference(MyEntity.class, original.getId());
    Collection c = entity.getSomeChildren(); // prints "select ... from MyEntity where id=?"
    original.setSomeChildren(c);
    return  original;
```

... hoping that it won't issue a database query, but it apparently does :(

Comment: Have you tried using caching solution like `EhCache`?

Comment: `getReference` still returns a proxy entity; it has to know if the entity exists in the DB so it knows to throw the `EntityNotFoundException` if it's not in the DB.

Comment: What would you do with this non-loaded lazy collection? Any method call on the collection would load it anyway.

Comment: @Dave: no. getReference assumes the entity exists in the DB. The javaodoc says: *the EntityNotFoundException is thrown when the instance state is first accessed*

Comment: @JB Nizet: Is a getting the value of a lazy collection property considered "instance state being accessed"? I need this because this is a generic load and the collection may be later thrown away.

Comment: @saintali: calling any method (size(), iterator(), add(), etc.) of a lazy collection will initialize the collection, i.e. trigger a SQL query to load its elements. I don't know what you mean by "the value of a collection", and don't understand which "instance state being accessed" you're talking about.

Comment: @JB Nizet; Ah. Although the Javadocs *also* say that the EM is permitted to throw the exception when getReference is called.

Comment: @Dave: yes: this is to allow getReference to be called even if proxies are not supported by the underlying EM. In this case, getReference is roughly equivalent to find, except it throws an exceptio instead of returning null.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I updated the question, I hope now it makes sense. This code is at loading site, so I don't yet know whether any method will be called on the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `select new MyEntity(...)` in your query means that you're using your MyEntity as a DTO: a detached object containing some fields of the actual MyEntity instance.

If you would like it to reference a lazy collection of children, just use `select e from MyEntity e ...`: you'll get an attached MyEntity instance, with its lazy (uninitialized) collection of children. And as soon as you call any method of the children collection, an additional query will be executed to load this collection.

If you persist on wanting to use a detached MyEntity, and you want to have a reference to its list of children, you'll indeed have to reload the entity (and thus gets its attached version), which will of course trigger an additional SQL query just to laod the entity again, with all its fields.

I would avoid using the MyEntity class as a DTO, and use a dedicated class instead, not containing the list of children. It will thus be clear to the caller code that an additional, ad-hoc HQL query will need to be executed to get the list of children.